# python 3.10 environment install by conda doesn't support manylinux2014 tag

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have a Python 3.10.12 envrioment install by conda 4.12.0 with the following command on a CentOS  7.5.1804 system

```bash
conda create -n py310 python==3.10.12
```

When I run `pip install open3d`, I get the below error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for open3d
```

And I debug with the following command I found the python environment doesn't support the manylinux_2_27 tag. All supported build of open3d can be found here: https://pypi.org/simple/open3d/

```
pip debug -v | grep cp310-manylinux
WARNING: This command is only meant for debugging. Do not use this with automation for parsing and getting these details, since the output and options of this command may change without notice.
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_16_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_15_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_14_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_13_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_11_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_10_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_9_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_8_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_7_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_6_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64
  cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64
```

I don't know the reason. Is there any way to workaround this issue?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/open3d/0.16.0/#files The only wheel for Python 3.10 on x64 is 
`open3d-0.16.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_27_x86_64.whl`, requires `manylinux_2_27`. I suspect it requires higher version of CentOS. You can try to compile from sources: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/compilation.html